Filtering with OData on More Properties but Returning a DTO with Fewer Properties in ASP.NET Core not possible
I am working on an ASP.NET Core project where I need to filter data based on all properties of an entity using complex OData query strings. However, the response should only include a subset of these properties in a Data Transfer Object (DTO).This does not seem to work for me.
I tried setting fewer properties in the DTO from the repository and more properties in the DTO from the controller. Then I used the mapper to ignore the properties not present in the repository DTO. This method did not work at all. I also tried using fewer properties in both DTOs, but then it couldn't filter on those properties. So, that is what I tried.
This is the working setup:
PandverschillenOdataController: ODataController function ->
[HttpGet] 
[EnableQuery] 
public IQueryable<PandVerschilDataTransferObject> Get() 
{     
return _dataQualityService.GetCachedPandVerschillen();     
                      .ProjectTo<PandVerschilDataTransferObject(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider); 
 }

Repository function ->
public IQueryable<PandVerschilServiceModel> GetPandVerschillen()
{
  return _context.PandVerschil
               .Select(verschil => new PandVerschilServiceModel
               {
                 PandNaam = verschil.PandNaam,
                 BagIdentificatie = verschil.BagIdentificatie,
                 Verschilpercentage = verschil.Verschilpercentage,
                 GeometrieVerschilMiddelpunt = verschil.GeometrieVerschilMiddelpunt,
                 Status = verschil.Status,
                 Oorzaken = verschil.Oorzaken,
                 OorzaakSuggesties = verschil.OorzaakSuggesties,
               });
} 

Class: GeneralMapperProfile: Profile ->
  CreateMap<PandVerschilServiceModel, PandVerschilDataTransferObject>()
.ForMember(dst => dst.GeometrieVerschilMiddelpunt, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GeometrieVerschilMiddelpunt != null ? GeometryConverter.ConvertTo(src.GeometrieVerschilMiddelpunt) : null));

program ->
builder.Services.AddAllServiceBasics()
.AddOData(options =>
{
// Sets all the options to enabled
options.Count().Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().
SetMaxTop(int.MaxValue); 
options.AddRouteComponents("v{version:apiVersion}/odata", new 
PandVerschilEdmModel().GetEdmModel());
});

PandverschilEdmModel function ->
public IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
  var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder
{
  Namespace = "PandVerschil",
  ContainerName = "PandVerschilContainer",
};

/*
 * IMPORTANT:
 *
 * 1) Do not set limitations on properties (like 
.IsNotSortable()) here, that doesn't work with base-classes. Use 
data annotations directly on the class members (example in the 
BaseMessage.cs)
 * 2) The naming of the entitySet is case-sensitive, making 
   everything lower-case does not work (controllers are not 
   mapped)
 */
 builder.EntitySet<PandVerschilDataTransferObject> ("PandverschillenOdata");

 return builder.GetEdmModel();
}


It's possible. We can't guess how you built your service or what URL you used . OData doesn't return DTOs nor does it use repositories. If you use an ODataController and return an IQueryable, the $select fields are used to construct the actual LINQ and therefore final SQL query. If you used the fake "repository" antipattern though (low level single-entity CRUD class over the high level multi-entity Unit-of-Work/DbContext), you prevent EF from working and are responsible for actually returning the correct data

Neither EF nor OData use "repositories" or mappers. Those are your own custom constructs. They're also common in bad articles claiming to show "best practices" and behind a lot of the problems in hundreds of Stack Overflow questions. The real Repository pattern is useful if you understand what it is about. AutoMapper is useful if you use it as intended, for the scenarios it's built. You can't just apply them to any project though "because best practices".

Thank you for your feedback. To clarify, I am indeed using an ODataController and returning an IQueryable. Here is a simplified version of my setup in my controller:
[HttpGet] [EnableQuery] public IQueryable<PandVerschilDataTransferObject> Get() {     var query = _dataQualityService.GetCachedPandVerschillen();     return query.ProjectTo<PandVerschilDataTransferObject>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider); }

Post your code in the question itself, along with the URL you used and the result you got. Include the OData configuration too. If you don't enable Select, the $select parameter won't work.

The Query Options doc page shows how that once Select is enabled with .AddOData(options => options.Select()...., it does affect what fields are returned. When GET http://localhost:6285/odata/Customers?$select=Name is used, only the Name fields are returned.

Post the .AddControllers().AddOData( configuration and the URL you used as well. Without options.Select() there's no column selection
